# Change A Div's CSS For A Certain Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$("#team").css("background-color","blue");
```

I'd like to turn the background colour of id:team to blue however I would only like to turn it  this colour for 4 seconds.

How do I do this?

I've Googled around but I couldn't find anything regarding changing css for a given time frame.

**Also, a fading out/in from/to the previous settings would be a nice touch.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it to only appear blue for 4 seconds you could do:

```
var element = $( "#team" );
var oldColor = element.css( "background-color" );
element.animate( { "background-color": "blue" } )
       .delay( 4000 )
       .animate( { "background-color": oldColor } );
```

You need jQuery UI to `.animate()`, otherwise you can just use `.css()`.

Comment: "inherit" will work if it didn't have some other explicit local style. So it works for me, because I didn't change my class's settings, i.e. it will just use the div's background-color as demonstrated by css code.

Comment: can we animate background color now in jQuery?

Comment: Oh you meant inherit as in inherit CSS style? Then yes inherit will work if the parent element has the same color as `oldColor`.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you still can't animate bg color in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/7Yc4n/.  mootools you can though.

Comment: You need jQuery UI to animate background color.

Comment: is it possible to set the css to a specific css class?

Comment: What you are looking for is the jQuery `.addClass()` method: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the timer feature:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
     $('#team').css('background-color', 'whatever'); 
}, 4000);
```

The second argument is a count in milliseconds of how long you'd like to wait before the first argument (a function) is called.

There's no built-in ability to say "go back to what it was before"; you'll have to remember the old value in your own code.

Comment: Thanks, you can use $('#team').css('background-color', 'inherit'); to go back to the previous settings. Thanks!

Comment: @JoseBazBaz yes "inherit" will work if it didn't have some other explicit local style.

Comment: is it possible to set the css to a specific css class?

Comment: @JoseBazBaz well yes but to do that you'd use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the jQuery UI plugin (perhaps due to its size) then you could do the animating manually.

See [the following code working in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5U7hL/).

```
function animblue(selector, from, to, step) {
    var
        target = $('#target'),
        color = from,
        next;
    next = function () {
        var hex = (Math.floor(color) < 16 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor(color).toString(16);
        target.css('background-color', '#' + hex + hex + 'ff');
        color += step;
        if (!((color < from && color < to) || (color > from && color > to))) {
            setTimeout(next, 10);
        }
    };
    next();
}

$('#action').on('click', function () {
    animblue('#target', 255, 0, -255 / 16);
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        animblue('#target', 0, 255, 255 / 16);
    }, 4000);
});​
```